# Javascript : Etch-a-sketch

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

I am a beginner in javascript and I have made this project as a part of [The odin project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-etch-a-sketch).
Feautres:

1. Draw by hovering the mouse on grid
2. Erase
3. Clear the entire sketch at once
4. Reset the grid size

I have created the grid using only flexbox.

Here is my code:

```js
function createGrid(grid, rowSize, colSize) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
    grid[i] = document.createElement("div");
    grid[i].setAttribute("id", "container");
    let pixels = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
      pixels[j] = document.createElement("div");
      pixels[j].setAttribute("id", "pixel");
      grid[i].appendChild(pixels[j]);
    }
  }
  return grid;
}

function appendArray(pDiv, cDiv) {
  cDiv.forEach((div) => pDiv.appendChild(div));
  return pDiv;
}

(() => {
  const GRID_WIDTH = 16;
  const GRID_HEIGHT = 16;
  const sketchEl = document.querySelector("#sketch");
  const eraseEl = document.querySelector("#erase");
  const buttonsEl = document.querySelector(".buttons");
  let gridCont = document.querySelector("#grid-container");
  let grid = [];
  let state;
  grid = createGrid(grid, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT);
  gridCont = appendArray(gridCont, grid);
  buttonsEl.addEventListener("click", changeState);

  gridCont.addEventListener("mouseover", eventHandler, false);

  function changeState(event) {
    state = event.target.id;
    switch (state) {
      case "reset":
        sketchReset();
        break;
      case "gridSize":
        sizeReset();
    }
  }
  function sketchReset() {
    const pixels = document.querySelectorAll("#pixel");
    pixels.forEach((pxl) =>
      pxl.setAttribute("style", "background-color:'transparent';")
    );
  }
  function sizeReset() {
    let size = parseInt(prompt("Enter grid size (MAX=100) : "));
    if (size <= 100) {
      grid.length = 0;
      grid = createGrid(grid, size, size);
      gridCont.innerHTML = "";
      gridCont = appendArray(gridCont, grid);
    }
  }
  function eventHandler(event) {
    if (event.target.id !== "pixel") {
      return;
    }
    changeColor(event);
  }
  function changeColor(event) {
    if (state === "eraser") {
      event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:'transparent';");
      return;
    }
    event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;");
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#header {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2em;
}
.button {
  font-size: x-large;
}
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 30em;
  width: 30em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-container > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid-container > div > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    <h1 id="header">Etch-a-sketch!</h1>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" id="sketch">Sketch</button>
        <button class="button" id="eraser">Erase</button>
        <button class="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="button" id="gridSize">Grid Size</button>
      </div>
      <div id="grid-container" class="grid-container"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to only focus on the Javascript code in my answer.

---

```js
function createGrid(grid, rowSize, colSize) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
    grid[i] = document.createElement("div");
    grid[i].setAttribute("id", "container");
    let pixels = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
      pixels[j] = document.createElement("div");
      pixels[j].setAttribute("id", "pixel");
      grid[i].appendChild(pixels[j]);
    }
  }
  return grid;
}
```

I'm not sure why this takes a `grid` argument, given that the name is *create*Grid. Just create the array within the function.

Secondly, ids are supposed to be unique. For a group of similar elements, you should use a class instead. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/whats-the-difference-between-an-id-and-a-class) for more info.

---

```js
function appendArray(pDiv, cDiv) {
  cDiv.forEach((div) => pDiv.appendChild(div));
  return pDiv;
}
```

There already is a function to append multiple children to an element: [`Element#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append). The invocation is a bit different, as you'll need to use spread syntax to pass an array, ie. `gridCont.append(...grid)`.

---

```
gridCont.addEventListener("mouseover", eventHandler, false);
```

`eventHandler` is an undescriptive name. I would rename it to something like `gridMouseover`.

---

```js
  function changeState(event) {
    state = event.target.id;
    switch (state) {
      case "reset":
        sketchReset();
        break;
      case "gridSize":
        sizeReset();
    }
  }
```

In my opinion, reset and gridSize shouldn't affect the global state, as they are one-time actions. As written, your code works, though restructuring the code will help for future modifications.

```js
  function changeState(event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "reset":
        sketchReset();
        break;
      case "gridSize":
        sizeReset();
        break;
      case "sketch":
      case "reset":
        state = event.target.id;
        break;
    }
  }
```

---

```js
const pixels = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");
```

*(code modified to align with the `createGrid` change)*

There's no need for `querySelectorAll` here - just use `document.getElementsByClassName("pixel")` for better performance and more code clarity.

---

```js
  function changeColor(event) {
    if (state === "eraser") {
      event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:'transparent';");
      return;
    }
    event.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;");
  }
```

This doesn't need to use the entire event object, just the pixel element that's being hovered, so only pass that as the argument.

---

Full code:

```js
function createGrid(rowSize, colSize) {
  let grid = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
    grid[i] = document.createElement("div");
    grid[i].setAttribute("class", "container");
    
    let pixels = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
      pixels[j] = document.createElement("div");
      pixels[j].setAttribute("class", "pixel");
    }
    
    grid[i].append(...pixels);
  }
  return grid;
}

(() => {
  const GRID_WIDTH = 16;
  const GRID_HEIGHT = 16;
  const sketchEl = document.querySelector("#sketch");
  const eraseEl = document.querySelector("#erase");
  const buttonsEl = document.querySelector(".buttons");
  let gridCont = document.querySelector("#grid-container");
  let state;
  let grid = createGrid(GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT);
  gridCont.append(...grid);

  buttonsEl.addEventListener("click", changeState);
  gridCont.addEventListener("mouseover", gridMouseover, false);

  function changeState(event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "reset":
        sketchReset();
        break;
      case "gridSize":
        sizeReset();
        break;
      case "sketch":
      case "reset":
        state = event.target.id;
        break;
    }
  }
  
  function sketchReset() {
    const pixels = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");
    Array.from(pixels).forEach((pxl) =>
      pxl.setAttribute("style", "background-color:'transparent';")
    );
  }
  
  function sizeReset() {
    let size = parseInt(prompt("Enter grid size (MAX=100) : "));
    if (size <= 100) {
      grid = createGrid(size, size);
      gridCont.innerHTML = "";
      gridCont.append(...grid);
    }
  }
  
  function gridMouseover(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains("pixel")) {
      return;
    }
    changeColor(event.target);
  }
  
  function changeColor(pixel) {
    if (state === "eraser") {
      pixel.setAttribute("style", "background-color:'transparent';");
      return;
    }
    pixel.setAttribute("style", "background-color:black;");
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#header {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2em;
}
.button {
  font-size: x-large;
}
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 30em;
  width: 30em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-container > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid-container > div > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    <h1 id="header">Etch-a-sketch!</h1>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" id="sketch">Sketch</button>
        <button class="button" id="eraser">Erase</button>
        <button class="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="button" id="gridSize">Grid Size</button>
      </div>
      <div id="grid-container" class="grid-container"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Some suggestions for future improvements:

- only draw pixels while the mouse is held - check out the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.
- display validation errors for `sizeReset`.